# Check for empty fields or insert everything?

Tags: php, mysql

What is better form data manipulation system?

(in this case when inserting the data into the database).

- Check which text fields have been filled and insert only those.
- Insert all the data, even the empty values from text fields. The database value is null in both cases, right?

I usually use the first method, but in this case i have A LOT of fields and really dont want to write code to check every single one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By The Way, "" Is not like NULL, "" is Empty String and Null is No Value At All.

You can verify if the Data is present by looping the dataset and verifying each variable if it has "" and then turn into NULL before insert into database.

The only case when a Text from Form will be NULL is if he wasn't into form, so the PHP will treat it like null.

Best pratice is to find a way to programatically loop into data and perform all the verifications needed, instead of write every single piece of data.

```
$safe_array = array();

foreach($data as $i => $v) {
    if($v=="") {
        $safe_array[$i] = null;
    }
    else if (custom_filter($v)) {
        $safe_array[$i] = null;
    } else {
        $safe_array[$i] = $v;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to check them anyway, right? How else would you know whether they should be inserted or not?

Or do you mean that some fields are unused completely by the form, so they are always null? In that case, you don't need to include them in your insert statement.

Comment: Fields are optional. (User decides which ones he wants to fill). My idea was to insert them anyway, the database record is empty in both cases, if you dont insert or if you insert an "empty string". Am i right?

Comment: I would insert them anyway then. Like I said, you would have to check them anyway to see if they are left empty. There is a difference though, between `NULL` (meaning no value) and an empty string. An empty string is a value of type string, with a length of 0 characters. `NULL` is no value at all. In MySQL a distrinction is made between the two, although for instance Oracle regards them the same.